# How to create BroadcastReceiver in NativeScript

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver, nativescript

Is it possible to create BroadcastReceiver in NativeScript?

Documentation talks about events, but there is no example of using BroadcastrReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

At present NativeScript for Android provides limited support for broadcast receivers. The main reason is that broadcast receivers can work on arbitrary thread. For example you can specify a `scheduler` when you call `registerReceiver` method. Right now we are experimenting with different multi-thread models and once we make a decision we will provide support for broadcast receivers as well.

That being said, you can use `registerReceiver` (manifest is not supported yet) to register custom broadcast receiver that will be scheduled on the main thread.

Comment: @Mihail Is there any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

For NativeScript 8 or + You can do:

```js
import { Utils, Application } from "@nativescript/core";

//Send broadcast
function sendBroadcast() {
  const context = Utils.android.getApplicationContext();
  const intent = new android.content.Intent("com.example.broadcast.NEW_BROADCAST_KEY");
  intent.putExtra("message", JSON.stringify({ foo: 0, bar: 1 }));
  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

//Listener
Application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver("com.example.broadcast.NEW_BROADCAST_KEY", (context, intent) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(intent.getStringExtra("message"))
  console.log(data);
})
```